# I just started with NESTJS and got this error

Tags: nestjs

{"statusCode":404,"message":"Cannot GET /posts","error":"Not Found"}

Comment: you're trying to make a `GET /posts` request but didn't have registered any controller with that route.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make GET requests where you have put @GET decorator. Similarly for a POST request to a POST decorator. For example, in Controller:

```
  @Post('getFoo')
  async getFoo(@Request() req) {
  //rest of the code goes here
  }
```

So in Postman, I choose the type of request as POST and, similarly for other requests such as GET.